# Cordite UI is not working while running network map service(codite)

Tags: local, corda, cordite

Cordite UI is not working on http://localhost:8080/ while running network map service.Even http://localhost:8080/swagger/swagger.json is working fine. I have checked java process on port 8080 and it's listing

Comment: Can I check a few things please: 1. in the browser window, what do you see if you open the browser's debug console? 2. what version are you using please? 3. how do you start the app? 3. did you recently do an upgrade?

Comment: @dazraf 1. This locahost page can’t be found (No web page was found for the web address: http://localhost:8080/)
2. M using master branch of network map service(“https://gitlab.com/cordite/network-map-service”)
3. Followed the steps through this link (“https://gitlab.com/cordite/network-map-service/blob/master/FAQ.md#1-show-me-how-to-set-up-a-simple-network”)
 hope above details will help to understand the problem

Comment: @dazraf I am able to run api on swagger ("http://localhost:8080/swagger") but not able to run "http://localhost:8080/"

Answer (score 0):

This is an older question but the comments have this right.

If you're able to see certain responses from your app (in this case on 8080) then this looks like it could potentially be a browser issue more than it is a corda issue per see.

Try the following steps:

- try accessing localhost:8080 with multiple browsers
- try clearing browser cache
- try to curl or ping the web app to ensure it's getting requests (it's possible part of the webserver failed or it's throwing exceptions)
- check the logs of the cordite UI to see what it does when you open the URL in your browser(s).
- if none of this works check if there's another part of the web UI that you didn't run. (unlikely here because you can get the swagger file but still)

best of luck!